# Remove duplicate entries from two post listings on one page

Tags: php, wordpress

I am quite new to wordpress and php, so I am searching solution on the following issue:
I have 3 elements on a page that are listing posts, filtered by categories.

1st Element lists from category A and B
2nd Element lists from category B and C
3rd Element lists from category B

Now I have a post that is in category A, B AND C and in some cases I do not want :
list it in the first
list it in the second element, as it is already listet in the first
but I want it listed in 3rd

My code reduced for each element

```
    <?php
        $multiargs = array(
            'cat' => get_field('block_cats'),
            'post_status' => 'publish',
        );
        $multiquery = new WP_Query( $multiargs ); 
        ?>

<?php while( $multiquery->have_posts() ) : $multiquery->the_post(); ?>
<--- layout for each post here ---->
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Want I was looking for is some argument to extend the query by something like "no duplicates if post is shown before"

Comment: Can you elaborate on `no duplicates if post is shown before` before where?  In this loop?  Somewhere else?

Comment: @HowardE thanks for asking: In this loop. 
Let´s assume: 
I have 3 loops on page in different content blocks. 
Loop 1 shows posts , Loop 2 shall not show post duplicates, if already shown in loop 1, Loop 3 shall show all posts - also if shown in 1 or 2